# Zooming a specific series with Sencha Charts

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I currently have a Sencha Line Chart which looks like this:

```
xtype: 'chart',
                    height: '100%',
                    store: 'ExperimentDataStore',
                    axes: [
                        {
                            type: 'numeric',
                            fields: [
                                'pmc1Value'
                            ],
                            grid: true,
                            minimum: 0,
                            position: 'left',
                            title: 'PMC1Value'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'numeric',
                            fields: [
                                'temperature'
                            ],
                            position: 'left',
                            title: 'test'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'numeric',
                            fields: [
                                'temperature'
                            ],
                            position: 'left',
                            title: 'pmc6Value'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'category',
                            fields: [
                                'timestamp'
                            ],
                            title: 'Name'
                        }
                    ],
                    series: [
                        {
                            type: 'line',
                            colors: [
                                'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
                            ],
                            style: {
                                smooth: false,
                                stroke: '#000'
                            },
                            xField: 'timestamp',
                            yField: 'temperature'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'line',
                            colors: 'rgba(0,200,0,0.3)',
                            style: {
                                smooth: true,
                                stroke: 'rgb(0,200,0)',

                            },
                            xField: 'timestamp',
                            yField: 'pmc1Value'
                        }
                    ],
                    interactions: [
                        {
                            type: 'panzoom',
                            zoomOnPanGesture: true,
                            axes: {
                                top: false,
                                right: false,
                                bottom: false,
                                left: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Currently the zoom action zooms the y Axis on the left side for all of my Chart series. But what I would like to achive is zooming only one specific Series and not all of them. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not use PanZoom on an individual Series. The PanZoom interaction is only configurable on the Axis level not the series level. Zooming an individual Series is not supported out of the box.

But assuming that it can be done, can you describe what behaviour you want to have by zooming on a specific series? Like  how do you want to visualize the other series? you will have distorted scales.